# SwiftSuspenders: “mutually injecting” classes?

Tags: robotlegs, swiftsuspenders

Does SwiftSuspenders support “mutually injecting” classes?

For example, if class `A` injects an instance of `B`, and `B` injects an instance of `A`:

```
class A {
    [Inject]
    public var b:B;
}
class B {
    [Inject]
    public var a:A;
}
```

And, if not, how can I fake this behaviour?

I ask because, when I tried to do this in my code, I started getting stack overflows… And it looks like they are being caused by SwiftSuspenders trying to inject `A` into `B` into `A` into `B` into…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is probably no. Circular dependencies are a trick. You could use setter injection and deliver it that way. Inject A into B via a setter that also sets B on A.

It might be worth filing a SS issue to resolve this type of thing.